# Inverse filter using Fourier transform

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, fft

I'm just starting out with image restoration and feel confused about some concepts 
Is an inverse filter same as deconvolution?
I wanted to apply a blur or an image(using a kernel) and then fourier the distorted image as well as kernel and divide so as to get the fourier of original image. Now, applying an inverse filter yeilds the original image. Is this approach correct?

What is the significance of sign and magnitude part of the image?
Thanks :)

Comment: This question is a bit broad and not really about programming. There are other stackexchanges like https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ more specialized on this. Just briefly: Deconvolution is the more general term, inverse Fourier filtering is one way of deconvolving data and division by the transformed kernel may not be possible for high frequencies (division by zero) and/or may amplify noise in the data, so you may also want to introduce some sort of regularization. Wikipedia has some really good pages on inverse filtering.

Comment: The inverse Fourier transform is actually the same as a direct Fourier transform ! (to a sign reversal)